# Is it possible to do an apt-get installation and continue it later?

Tags: installation, apt

Let's say I want to install something big... (kde for example) but I'm doing it in a place with a very poor internet conection, so I want to stop it, and doing it later. But I don't want to start all over again. Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do `apt-get install -d  STUFF` which will download everything
to the cache but won't act on it.

Later when you have a better
connection you can just drop the -d and apt will download the
rest if needed and begin installing from the cache: `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Answer (score 3):

If you kill an apt-get while it's still in the stage of fetching packages then yes, it will resume fetching pretty much from where it left off - the archvies it has fetched so far will be kept in /var/cache/apt/archives.

This is the directory that gets cleaned up by `apt-get clean`, incidentally.

If you kill it after it's finished fetching and has started configuring/installing then you're in much deeper water and I wouldn't really want to try it ;)

Answer (score -2):

Or, start the installation with GNU Screen. Just run `screen` by itself, and it will open a new window with a shell inside it. If you run commands here, then press Ctrl-d (`^d`), the window will "detach" from your current terminal, but it will stay running in the background: run `screen -x` to get back to it.

This also works for long-running command such as apt-get install [all of KDE]: just start the apt-get install command inside a screen window and press ^d. Then later, simply re-attach using `screen -x` and see if it's done.

Screen has much more options: `^a c` will create new windows (use `^a 1` to go to the first one, `^a n` to go to the one "to the right", etc). See http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/ for the manual!

***Edit***: Of course, the computer running `screen` windows cannot be restarted, or the windows will be lost.